# Javac invalid flag error while using commands "-d" and "-cp."

Tags: linux, terminal, javac

I working on an assignment that wants to optimize some of my old code. I am currently using one of my old game projects problem after a few years the game no longer seems to function properly. I'm using the same instructions that I wrote in my readme file (which it has worked before) which bascially sets up my files like this

```
|Directory Name
   |src
     |main
     |map
     |state
     |music
     |musicEffects
     |images
   |bin
```

(these are just folders)

then I compile as such: (my main file is in the main folder)

```
javac -d bin/ -cp src src/main/Main.javac
```

and run:

```
java - cp bin main/Main
```

problem is I get an error like this upon compiling:

```
javac: invalid flag: src/main/Main.javac
usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I've tired using bracketing it up but I keep getting the same error

Comment: Try change class file to `Main.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Your source file is not named correctly. Instead of ending with `.javac`, it needs to end with `.java`.

Here's a similar set up locally – my output directory is `out` (instead of your `bin`). If I have a file named `Main.javac` as you do, it produces the same error:

```
$ javac -d out -cp src src/main/Main.javac
error: invalid flag: src/main/Main.javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

After correcting the filename to end in `.java`, compilation is successful and a `.class` file is generated in my output directory:

```
$ javac -d out -cp src src/main/Main.java
$ ls out
Main.class
```